# Monitor CPU usage for Win 2012 R2 with alerts on external clients

Tags: monitoring

I want to get alerted when a customers Win server is going on 90% usage for longer than 5 minutes. Maybe with a Simple listner application on the client side. but how can i realize this?

Already thought about Peformance analyzer sending a mail by running a simple program (SwithMail).

Any thoughts??

Note: I am not a coder ;)

Comment: There's like a bazillion products and services that do this. Google should help you find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to alert only after 5 minutes, you can create a performance counter alert following this guide: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2424491.

If you need the 5 minutes timespan, you can use this little powershell script:

```
$TaskName = "SendAlert"

function alert-action()
{
    #stuff when alert happens
    Start-ScheduledTask $TaskName
}    

$Counter = 0
while($true)
{
    if(gwmi "win32_processor" | Select -ExpandProperty LoadPercentage) {
        $Counter ++
        if($Counter -eq 5)
        {
            alert-action
        }
    } else {
        $Counter = 0
    }

    Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

To correctly use this, you need to create a scheduled task to run this powershell script on the windows startup. Then you need to create a task called "SendAlert" (or any name you change it if you change the variable value on this line: `$TaskName = "SendAlert"`) and configure this task to send email or whatever you like.

On the script I made a function called `alert-action`. You can add any powershell line inside it if you want. Something like send email using powershell (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) instead of using scheduled task.

Comment: little powershell script is real world ? using alert downgrow performance ?